# Java switch statment, break statement unreachable

Tags: java

I am working on a program that is a simple game. I'm using a switch statement to return the file location of images that are assigned to buttons. In order to do this I am using a switch statement inside a method called "get Image View" it returns a string that can be fed into an image view that I will need to compare the image in the button to another image elsewhere. I think I may be over-explaining, anyway. my IDE (NetBeans) is telling me that my break statement is unreachable and I can not figure out why. I have used a switch statement that looks very similar to mine and there is an example in my textbook that is also very similar. I know that I still need to have a default return statement I just want to know what's up with my break statements. Thank you in advance!

```
      public String getImageView(int button)
  {
      switch(button)
      {
          case 0: System.out.println("error");
          case 1:  return "1.png";
                   break;
          case 2:  return "2.png";
                   break;
          case 3:  return "3.png";
                   break;
          case 4:  return "4.png";
                   break;
          case 5:  return "5.png";
                   break;
          case 6:  return "6.png";
                   break;
          case 7: return "7.png";
                  break;
          case 8: return "8.png";
          case 9: return "9.png";
          case 10: return "10.png";

      }

  }
```

Comment: You do not need any of the `break` statements. Just remove all `break` statements and it will work fine.

Comment: ... because the breaks are unreachable—you return before them. Seems pointless since you could just build a string, or put the image names in an array or map anyway, but that’s a separate issue.

Comment: You are using return statement before break.  That's why..

Comment: plain java, not specific to fx

Comment: I just realized why it's unreachable. I feel dumb. Just in case anyone else has this issue, the reason the break statements are unreachable is that the return statement exits the switch statement and closes the method.   (posted this as an answer and it got deleted for seemingly no reason. I was not given a reason.)

Answer (score -1):

You can try something like below :

```
public String getImageView(int button){
String imageViewName = "";
      switch(button)
      {
          case 0: System.out.println("error");
          case 1:  imageViewName = "1.png";
                   break;
          case 2:  imageViewName = "2.png";
                   break;
          case 3:  imageViewName = "3.png";
                   break;
          case 4:  imageViewName = "4.png";
                   break;
          case 5:  imageViewName = "5.png";
                   break;
          case 6:  imageViewName = "6.png";
                   break;
          case 7: imageViewName = "7.png";
                  break;
          case 8: imageViewName = "8.png";
                  break;
          case 9: imageViewName = "9.png";
                  break;
          case 10: imageViewName = "10.png";
                  break;
      }
      return imageViewName;
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: please accept answer if this solution works. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Well switch-state-statements behaves not like a big if-else-statement.
Consider this code:

```java
int a = 0;
switch (a) {
  case 0:
    //do something
    break;
  case 1:
    //do something else
    break;
  default:
    //default case
}
```

Here the first case will be triggered as you can tell by the value of `a`.

If you want to first case be executed but also want to slip in the second case anyway you can omit the `break` in the first case.

So this code:

```
int a = 0;
switch (a) {
  case 0:
    System.out.println("case 0");
  case 1:
    System.out.println("case 1");
    break;
  default:
    //default case
}
```

will output:

```
case 0
case 1
```

just like it is in your Code.

So maybe you should consider the `break;` in your first case. Otherwise it will execute the `println` but also returning `1.png`.

Comment: `switch-state-statements are some sort of weird in behaviour if you have not worked much with it` - behavior of language feature does not depend on your experience.

Comment: This doesn’t answer the original question.